# SSL for Wildcard Sub-Domains

Tags: ssl, dns, wildcard-subdomain

I am trying to setup wildcard sub-domain. So my domain is www.mydomain.com so anything comes like this test.mydomain.com, welcome.mydomain.com will work, that is fine.

When it comes to SSL, if I am buying SSL for www.mydomain.com then will that same SSL certificate works for test.mydomain.com, welcome.mydomain.com? Since they are not real sub-domains just virtual.

If not do I need to buy wildcard SSL?

If I think technically all the wildcard sub-domains will point to same root folder and IP. From there using my code I will deliver different content. In that case my SSL certificate for www.mydomain.com will also work for test.mydomain.com right? I am not sure.

Any Guess?

Comment: Your question is similar to this one - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684082/is-a-wildcard-ssl-cert-neccesary-if-all-sub-domains-point-to-the-website-root][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684082/is-a-wildcard-ssl-cert-neccesary-if-all-sub-domains-point-to-the-website-root

Answer (score 0):

NAME in the SSL certificate must exactly match domain name of the site. You need wildcard certificate. Non-wildcard will produce a wrong-site warning.